# Intel 4 Series express - disabling hardware acceleration

Tags: windows-7, drivers, intel-graphics

In Windows 7, I want to disable hardware acceleration on a laptop with an integrated graphics chipset (Intel 4 Series express) to do some debugging.

I go to Control Panel | Appearance and Personalization | Display | Screen Resolution | Advanced Settings | Troubleshoot, and to my dismay, the "Change settings" button is disabled (i.e. grayed out).

The Intel driver graphics properties offer no solution for changing hardware acceleration settings. Also, I do have the latest driver installed.

Do I have any other way to disable hardware acceleration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish the same end goal by disabling the driver from the Device Manager.

For future reference:
Go to Computer | Manage | Device Manager | Display Adapters. Right click your display adapter and choose Properties. Go to the Driver tab. Click the Disable button.

Comment: This is a poor answer, unfortunately. Disabling the driver not only disables acceleration, but also disables power management features, like blanking the screen! When I disable the driver on a Sony Vaio Laptop, the "Sleep" command in the Shutdown menu becomes grayed out; the system is not able to sleep.